SqlConnection close but temporary tables not removed
I have a parent form that opens a child form. The child form opens a SQL connection that I need to create global temporary tables (named with double ##).
Closing the child form closes the connection, but the temporary tables remain standing. They are removed once the parent form is also closed, even if the connection is already closed. How is it possible?

The connection goes back to the pool, and is only reset when it's reused. Why are you using global temp tables anyway, why not local? And why not just explicitly DROP it?

Better question, why are you using temporary tables at all when opening forms etc

While far from ideal, I guess using global temp tables is one way of sharing data between pages using different connections in the same user interface session. You do need to be careful to ensure unique names to avoid accidental cross polluting data between two different sessions, or even between two separate pages open in the same user login session. (Users sometimes like to do that.)  It would be much better if you could find a better way to share data between UI components that doesn't go through the database.

Thanks for the comments. The purpose of the temporary tables is not important, let's stick to the question. Why do the tables remain standing when closing the child form also closes the connection to the database?

@Charlieface, is correct. I cleaned the pool and the problem is solved. Thank you!
